# Python calling different class variables with one argument in decision tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to make a decision tree for tictactoe with classes, and I cant get the function to call different class variables each time.

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, player, state):
    self.possible = poss_moves(state)
    self.player = player
    self.local_state = state
    self.score = 0
    self.one = None
    self.two = None
    self.three = None
    self.four = None
    self.five = None
    self.six = None
    self.seven = None
    self.eight = None
```

If i try and call the new child nodes with this function, it doesnt work. If i type out the code with node.one, node.two, etc.. it works, but i feel like there must be a way to make this function work. Ive tried passing it as a string, just putting node.one as the argument, assigning node.one to a variable

```
def digger(self, node, child):
    temp = copy.deepcopy(node.local_state)
    temp[node.possible[0][0]][node.possible[0][1]] = node.player
    if len(poss_moves(temp)) == 0 or wincon.win_check(temp) == node.player:
        child = End_State(temp)
        node.score += child.score
    else:  
        if node.player == 2:
            child = Node(1, temp)
            self.deeper(child)
            node.score += child.score
        else:
            child = Node(2, temp)
            self.deeper(child)
            node.score += child.score
    node.possible.pop(0)



def deeper(self, node):
    while len(node.possible) > 0:
        self.digger(node, node.one)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.two)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.three)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.four)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.five)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.six)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.seven)
        if len(node.possible) == 0:
            break
        self.digger(node, node.eight)
```

Comment: Start by reading on [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)...

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, but any time you have many named arguments where the names incorporate numbers (either as `foo1`, `foo2` or in your case, numbers spelled out), you probably should be using a list instead of separate variables.

Comment: Thank you got me on the right track i had to use an empty dictionary but it works. Im making a decision tree of all the possible moves in tic-tac-toe, for a simpe AI, didnt want to post the whole thing.